# Adding soap:encodingStyle attribute to soap:body while using cxf:jaxws-client

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, cxf, mule

I am accessing a rpc/literal style webservice from my flow in mule.

The binding part of the wsdl looks like below :

```
<binding name="AppWebServiceBinding" type="interface:AppWebService">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"   />
    <operation name="submitApplication">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="rpc"  />
        <input name="submitApplicationRequest"  >
            <soap:body
                encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml"
                namespace="http://tempuri.org/fsg.ejb.webservice.AppWebService"
                parts="ele" use="literal" type="soap:tBody"  />
        </input>
        <output name="submitApplicationResponse">
            <soap:body
                encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml"
                namespace="http://tempuri.org/fsg.ejb.webservice.AppWebService" use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
```

Then I am passing expectedobject to the http:outbound with cxf:jaxws-client

```
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://serviceapp:9080/service_war/servlet/rpcrouter"   
        doc:name="Generic">
        <cxf:jaxws-client clientClass="com.fsg.generated.AppWebServiceService"
            wsdlLocation="com/fsg/generated/AppWebServiceService.wsdl"              
            operation="submitApplication"   port="AppWebServicePort"                 
            doc:name="SOAP">                
            <cxf:inInterceptors  >
            <spring:bean id="inLogger" 
                class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />                  
            </cxf:inInterceptors>
            <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean id="outLogger"
                class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>              
        </cxf:jaxws-client>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
```

But when I look into the logs to see the message being sent to the outbound I don't see the soap:encodingStyle attribute in that. This is causing the problem as the service cannot process the message without this.

Given below is the outbound message I could see in the log.

```
    Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: http://serviceapp:9080/service_war/servlet/rpcrouter
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {SOAPAction=[""]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header>
<mule:header xmlns:mule="http://www.muleumo.org/providers/soap/1.0">
<mule:MULE_CORRELATION_ID>dfd31e6c-6575-11e2-9b8a-b1b06bd39882</mule:MULE_CORRELATION_ID>   <mule:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE>-1</mule:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE>
<mule:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE>-1</mule:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE>
</mule:header>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ns1:submitApplication xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/fsg.ejb.webservice.AppWebService">
<ele>
<MyApp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://mysample.org">  
  <UserAuth>  ............
```

It can be seen that the namespace is picked from the wsdl but not the encodingStyle.

Expected output is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header>
<mule:header xmlns:mule="http://www.muleumo.org/providers/soap/1.0">
.......
</mule:header>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ns1:submitApplication xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/fsg.ejb.webservice.AppWebService"  soap:encodingStyle="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap/literalxml" >
<ele>
<MyApp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://mysample.org">  
  <UserAuth>  ............
```

How can I set the soap:encodingStyle attribute in this?

Comment: Not sure if this help your case but you could try message-properties-transformer something like the following <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
<add-message-property key="encodingStyle" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encod...;
<add-message-property key="soap:encodingStyle" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encod...;
</message-properties-transformer>

Comment: Razh, I have tried this. But no luck. :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. on mule documentation is suggested to use it like the following I am not sure if you already tried it this way.         <outbound>
<pass-through-router>
<vm:outbound-endpoint path="middle" exchange-pattern="request-response">
<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
 <!-- Propagate 'myFooProperty' from the inbound to outbound -->
 <add-message-property key="myFooProperty" value="#[header:INBOUND:myFooProperty]"/>
 </message-properties-transformer>
 </vm:outbound-endpoint>
 </pass-through-router>
</outbound>

Comment: I tried it that way also. I even tried with different scopes. But its not shown in the outbound message.

Comment: How are you expecting your output to look like?

Comment: Added my expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that it is not working. 
May be you could try the XSLT transformer to add the encoding style to the input and then get it processed. This is just a work around.

Comment: Currently I have implemented it that way. Looking for a straight solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that the encodingStyle attribute information can't appear in the body element, only in a child.

Comment: I could see that the namespace is picked and shown in the body tag properly. But the encodingStyle is not showing up. Any idea how to solve this?